# TensorFlow: embedding model uses too much GPU memory unnecessarily

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with knowledge graph embeddings in TensorFlow and I am having problems scaling it up:

TensorFlow maintains the gradient of each batch sample with respect to *all embeddings*, even though each sample is only directly associated with three embeddings.

In theory, for each batch it should only be necessary to bring to GPU memory the gradients of the embeddings associated with the present sample. This would massively decrease memory usage, with more memory overhead.

Is there a way to be more memory efficient when batching the embeddings?

I am using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` without partitioning. I have tried paritioning with `tf.fixed_size_partitioner` but the memory usage was similar.